# Get text from tag with attribute jsoup

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup, element

Im trying get the text from a tag "Data" with name="telefono" but I can't solve it:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Iglesia </name>
    <description> Abril </description>

    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name='description'>
            <value>4444</Data>
        <Data name='phone'>
            <value>5555</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.5191416,38.9848326,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I have a "for" that select all placemark:

```
for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element i : e.select("Placemark"))
```

I have tried all possibilities to get the value of the the phone 5555

but I don't know it, always get all data phone and description.

```
System.out.println((i.select("ExtendedData").text()));
System.out.println((i.select("ExtendedData").select("Data").tagName("phone").text()));
System.out.println("(i.select("ExtendedData").tagName("phone").text()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only `5555` then you can use `text()` of `<Data name='phone'>`. If there can be more of such elements then you may need to add more data about its ancestors/parents but for example you posted this should be enough:

```
System.out.println(doc.select("data[name=phone]").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println((i.select("ExtendedData").select("Data").tagName("phone").text()));

The above code doesn't work because the `tagName` method will update the tag name of all selected `Data` elements. Let's say the below element is selected:

```
<Data name='phone'><value>5555</value></Data>
```

Calling the `tagName` method would turn it into:

```
<phone name='phone'><value>5555</value></phone>
```

Instead try this:

```
System.out.println( i.select("ExtendedData > Data[name=phone]").text() )
```